# How to create a crud on DSpace?

Tags: java, xslt, dspace

I wanted to know if you have any feature in dspace that enables the easy creation of CRUD but with other tables in same database. I know do that to an external application would be easier. I need to do something immediately a system of "crud", so I'm evaluating the options, do something outside would be fast. But is there any option to do this with a feature of dspace? what level of complexity for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good answers to questions here if people can understand what it is you are asking.

Comment: As noted, it's very unclear what you are asking. At a basic level though, DSpace has both a Java API and a [REST API](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/REST+API) that provide CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functionality for all objects it handles.  But, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not compressible enough. In case it would be a CRUD using DSpace but with the same database but with the other tables. Something that does not harm the database and application. it is possible to use the REST API with other tables in the same database?

Comment: I looked superficially API module REST provides a programming interface for DSpace Communities, collections, items and Bitstreams. This API provides support to build something that does not use native tables created automatically, but custom tables to create something internal however without harming the system and the database.

Comment: The DSpace REST API only understands the DSpace data model (which is stored in DSpace database tables).  It sounds like you are expecting it to recognize *additional, custom tables* in your database? If so, DSpace won't do that, as they are not part of the DSpace data model. You'd have to create your own Java or REST API to interact with those custom tables, or extend DSpace's Java or REST API to interact with those custom tables.

Comment: However, it *is* possible for you to create custom tables in the same database as the DSpace database tables (and create your own API to interact with them).  It's just worth noting that, by default, DSpace is going to ignore any additional database tables you create, as they are not part of the DSpace data model.

Comment: In this case are different information and i think this is not something the dspace needs:

For example, it would be a record with information from an educational institutions, who wish to be repository partners. If your registration was approved or validated by any administrator. The instituitions could index your content in the repository. Such  as "CRUD" personalized.